# Wattmeter drawing with Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

How can I draw a wattmeter using LaTeX and `circuitikz`? I want to use the one with a circle and a cross inside.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz

Comment: There's no mention of 'wattmeter'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no `wattmeter` in the `circuitikz`, you need to draw one. Here the solution modifies the DC voltage source and create a `wattmeter` via `newcommand` that takes one argument for label

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\newcommand{\wattmeter}[1] 
{  % #1 = name
\draw[thick] (#1) circle (12pt);
\draw[rotate=45,line width=1pt]   (#1) +(0,-12pt) -- +(0,12pt);
\draw[rotate=-45,line width=1pt]  (#1) +(0,-12pt) -- +(0,12pt);
}

\begin{document}  
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (-1,0) node[ground] {} to[V,l=$10V$] (-1,2) to[R=$4\Omega$] (2,2) to[R=$2\Omega$,] (4,2);
\draw (4,2) to[L, l=$\frac{1}{5}F$] (4,0);
\draw (2,2) to[V,color=white,name=M1] (2,0);
\wattmeter{M1}
\draw (-1,0) to[short](4,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great idea. How would I draw the name of the wattmeter?

Comment: Use label as `l=M1`, right after the name=M1. If you need it on the left hand side, use l_=M1. Same as the skill in circuitikz.